# What is the correct way to use apposition?

Tags: appositions

I know that this question was probably already discussed dozens of times, but either it is me who can't find any information, or maybe it's actually not that important of a matter as I think

So my question is what is an apposition, and how do we use is? I have the basic idea of it being the thing that tells us additional information about the subject and usually put in commas

But could you please give me some more information on that matter (maybe by what parts os speech it is formed, or to what parts of a sentence it can refer or its place in the sentence) I will be very much obliged if you help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apposition is a rather complex notion and apparently not everybody agrees on what is its actual extent ([encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)).

> Il y a plusieurs constructions syntaxiques comprenant une partie considérée comme telle par divers grammairiens et aucune de leurs définitions ne couvre la notion dans toutes ces constructions, des facteurs sémantiques et syntaxiques divers y étant impliqués.

The following general definition given in the same reference is very good.

> Au sens le plus large, l’apposition est un mot ou un groupe de mots associé à un terme de la phrase, qui désigne la même réalité que ce terme mais d’une autre manière (identité de référence). Le plus souvent, on considère comme apposition une entité disjointe, c’est-à-dire séparée du terme auquel elle est apposée par une pause dans la parole et une virgule à l’écrit, mais il y a aussi des entités conjointes considérées comme des appositions. Les entités appelées appositions sont diverses quant à leur nature.

The following link provides a good start for a study of apposition: https://www.lelivrescolaire.fr/manuel/38/francais-4e/chapitre/382/fiches-de-grammaire/page/692773/l-apposition/lecon

On the basis of this presentation of "apposition" I'll try and explain essential principles defining this grammatical concept. The units in apposition are in bold type and the examples due to my own invention are labelled "[user **LPH**]".

**I**

**1/**     An earthlier definition than that given above is also helpful. A unit in apposition is connected to a noun or noun phrase as a way of adding information concerning the basic entity represented by that noun. It implies a further characterisation of that entity. In other words, given all entities that noun stands for, the unit placed in apposition to that noun narrows down the category (which can consist of only one element) or provides more details.

- **Étoile comme toute autre**, le soleil nous donne la vie. (*no category, added information only: a star as any other*) [user **LPH**]
- Des étoiles lointaines, **peu brillantes**, ne furent découvertes que plus tard. (*the category of far-away stars that shine little as seen from Earth*) [user **LPH**]

**2/**     A unit placed in apposition can be

- a noun,
- a noun phrase,
- a pronoun,
- a verb in the infinitive.

Some grammarians add the  following elements ([réf.](https://preparerlecrpe.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/grammaire-fiche-9-attribut-et-apposition.pdf)):

- an "adjectif qualificatif" (mobile)
- a past participle
- a "participe présent"
- a " subordonnée complétive"
- a "subordonnée relative adjective explicative"

*Examples*

- Sa fille, **pauvre enfant malade**, ne suscitait que la pitié.
- La directrice **elle-même** s'occupait de l'éducation de son jeune fils; elles étaient plusieurs enseignantes à faire cela dans l'école maintenant. [user **LPH**]
- Elle cherchait à satisfaire le premier des besoins, **manger**.

**3/**     A unit in apposition can be suppressed without causing an error in the syntax, without causing the resulting  meaning to be nonsense.

- Le soleil nous donne la vie.
- Des étoiles lointaines ne furent découvertes que plus tard.

**4/**    Amongst the various types of appositional structures those that do not consist in a simple juxtaposition have the property of  allowing for various places of the unit in apposition; there are two essential sorts of these structures that make for mobility: those for which the unit is set off between comma and that for which there is no such commas (those last can be difficult to make out).

- **Enfant difficile**, Alain ne mange pas de viande si elle n'est pas bien cuite. [user **LPH**]
- Alain, **enfant difficile**,  ne mange pas de viande si elle n'est pas bien cuite.
- Les enfants **eux-mêmes** ont compris que cela ne se ferait pas. [user **LPH**]
- **Eux-mêmes** les enfants ont compris que cela ne se ferait pas.

Remark    Certain units in  apposition, juxtaposed to the noun phrase they are connected to, are not mobile.

- le romancier **Victor Hugo** – le Roi **Louis XIV**

**5/**     For  the type of apposition in which the unit is set off by means of commas or introduced by a colon several units can be inserted, all separated by commas.

- **Fatigué par tout ce travail, dégouté par ses collaborateurs oisifs, encouragé par ses enfants**, Jean avait abandonné le projet. [user **LPH**]
- La pomme, **bien rouge, d'un luisant peu commun**, avait l'air appétissante mais elle était pourrie. [user **LPH**]
- Cette boite renfermait des clous : **des petits, des  neufs et des rouillés, des clous de type ancien, de rares clous comme des clous de tapisserie**…

**II**

In this treatment of apposition 4 structures are considered. It should not be inferred that any type of unit can be used in any structure; for instance after a colon are never found subordinate clauses or pronouns.

**1/** The unit is set off between commas.

- Sa fille ne l’intéressait plus, **enfant condamnée avant l’heure**.

**2/** The unit is introduced by a colon.

- La Thénardier exigeait de nombreuses tâches de Cosette : **balayer, nettoyer, frotter, astiquer**.

**3/** The unit is appended to the noun phrase by means of an "*expletif*" (*French: linking word without much meaning*).

- la ville **de Chartres** • le mois **de juillet**

**4/** The unit is introduced without ponctuation.

- Le chien **lui-même** se tenait à l'écart de l'inconnu. [user **LPH**]

**III**

**1/**     When an apparent apposition unit set off between commas is constituted of an "*adjectif qualificatif*" a special function akin to that of "*adjectif épithète*" is the function considered, not apposition; this spécial function is called "*fonction d'épithète détachée*".

- Épuisée, la jeune femme ne pouvait s’occuper de Cosette. (*Épuisée: épithète détachée*)

**2/**    When the unit in apposition is a pronoun placed after the verb, care must be taken not to confuse it with an "*attribut du sujet*" or a "*complément circonstanciel*"¹.

- Éléonore était restée  elle-même tout le temps de cette cohue. (*attribut du sujet « Éléonore »*) [user **LPH**]

A pronoun (or noun phrase with a pronoun for head) in a function of apposition can only be found with a verb of action, never a state verb, but that does not warrant the function being that of apposition.

- Joseph, **déjà quelqu'un dans l'usine**, n'y voyait pas son avenir. [user **LPH**]
- Joseph, **lui**, n'y voyait pas son avenir. [user **LPH**]
- Elle avait soigné le chien elle-même. • Elle avait soigné elle-même le chien, les oiseaux et les deux chats. (*Here, "elle-même" is connected to the verb and means "by herself", "without help" and not, as in the case of the apposition, "herself"; therefore we have a "complément circonstanciel de manière".*) [user **LPH**]

**3/**    Attention, ne pas confondre apposition et complément du nom.

- la ville **de Chartres** : Chartres est une apposition au nom ville. (*The city is called Chartres; the city and Chartres are the same reality, to take up the words in the general definition.*)
- la cathédrale de Chartres (*"Chartres" and "cathédrale" name two realities, and the preposition shows a relation of one belonging to the other. The fonction of "Chartres" is* complément du nom « cathédrale »)

¹<sub>The function "*complément circonstanciel*" was added by myself (user **LPH**).</sub>